# C# how to use user's inputted data for use in the application

Tags: c#, deployment

I have a program that I would like to sell to small companies. I would like for the user to type in their company name during install, so I can use the name in the menu title or for any other general uses where the company name should appear!
Where is the best place to store their info, app.config or the database?
How would I go about getting the information from the user during install?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your setup query the name of the user and store it wherever you want to have it saved. I would prefer the app.config and make it a machine setting.

Comment: Is there a tutorial explaining how one would do that?

Comment: Have a look at the MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/717cfce0-3061-400f-9ea3-069f73f3a473

Comment: As I already mentioned; I would use a machine setting located in the app.config

Comment: My customActionData's property is /Message="[MESSAGE]". How to I use that in my program?

Comment: You have to implement the installer component as well.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Here is a tutorial that I was looking for. Raquila.com/software/configure-app-config-application-settings-during-msi-install/